# How to use dlookup in access 2007 with multiple criteria, one of them being in date format?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Advance/Miscellaneous Exp table where there are 4 fields as follows,
Employer Name, Advance Expense, Miscellaneous Expense, Adv_Miscl_Date.

I have a form something like this
Employee Name:
Last_date:
Advance:
Miscellaneous:

When the last_date field gets focus, it displays the latest date from advance/miscellaneous exp table with respect to the employee name.
Now in the next field i.e the Advance field, I want the latest advance to be displayed. I tried the following with dlookup but kept getting syntax error or mismatch error.

```
Private Sub Adv()
[Adv]=Dlookup("Advance","Adv_Miscl_Exp","[Emp_Name]=Forms![Calculate Salary]![Emp_Name]" AND "    [Adv_M_Date]=Forms![Calculate Salary]![Last_date]") 
End Sub
```

What is the right syntax? How do i use dlookup with one criteria as employee name and the other criteria as the advance/miscellaneous date

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: try this one: `[Adv] = Dlookup("Advance", "Adv_Miscl_Exp", "[Emp_Name]= '" & Forms![Calculate Salary]![Emp_Name] & "' AND [Adv_M_Date]= #" & Forms![Calculate Salary]![Last_date] & "#")
`

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
Private Sub Adv()
    [Adv] = Dlookup("Advance", "Adv_Miscl_Exp", "[Emp_Name] = '" & Forms![Calculate Salary].Emp_Name & "' AND [Adv_M_Date] = #" & Forms![Calculate Salary].Last_date & "#") 
End Sub
```

For the correct syntax on DLookups, I tend to use the following page;
http://access.mvps.org/access/general/gen0018.htm